# Keep line with specific word and two lines above in Unix log

Tags: unix, grep, logfile

I have a long log file where I want to keep only the lines with the word 'change' and two lines above this line. how can I do it in Unix?

Comment: I also added later another question: if I want to improve the grep below, and use grep command which find line with the word 'failed', and copy all the lines above until it gets to a line with the work 'task' (include that line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier (I've found) if you can copy the file to Linux (unless you have cygwin or some other similar utility) and use grep.
The command would be:  `grep -B 2 change your.log`

That will find the lines with change and include the two previous lines before each change line.

=====

You could get the desired lines in Notepad++, but I've not (yet) found an easy way to do the same, but it is possible.  It all depends on what you mean by "long log file", as this effort could take some time:

1. First, use Search => Mark...
2. input the 'change' search term
3. check the 'Bookmark Line' check box
4. click the 'Mark All' button.

...at this point, all lines that have 'change' will show a bookmark to the left.

5. Move to the top of the file, if not already there
6. Press F2 to jump to the next bookmark
7. At the left, click the two lines above to also appear as bookmarks (make them have the same bookmark indication as the change line)
8. Repeat steps 6 and 7 for all the change lines, until you have all the "triplets" of bookmarks covered (the line with change and the two previous lines)
9. After all the bookmarks are set, then do: Search => Bookmark => Remove Unmarked Lines

There may be other ways in Notepad++ that someone might know, but I've used these steps for other needs. F2 is helpful to jump between bookmarks, so this can potentially help speed the process.

Comment: Do the number of lines vary before failed, or is there a constant number?  If a constant, like always 10 lines, then you can simply change the value to the -B option, like so  -B 10. g

Comment: its vary. is it still possible?

Comment: I don't believe grep will "look back" into the previous lines, unfortunately. You might have to simply use a value that will get the info even though some of the lines might be irrelevant. However, you might be able to alter the grep search to only find the task and failed lines, if this could be an alternative? (assuming the in-between lines do not also have 'task' or 'failed' in their entries)